# Unit polynomial factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wanted to know if $\sum_{i=1}^n x^{i-1}$ has some square in its prime factorisation for $x\neq 1$ an integer. $(n\ge 3)$.
I checked for small values especially $n=3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=12032$ and $n=4$, you have that
$$
\sum_{i-1}^4 12032^{i-1}=1742005677825=3^2\times 5^2\times 7\times 17\times 191\times 340633.
$$
**Edit:** In the mean time, I found many values of $x$ such that $\sum_{i-1}^n x^{i-1}$ has squares in its prime factorisation. The smallest for $n=3$ is $x=22$, since
$$
\sum_{i-1}^3 22^{i-1}=507=3\times 13^2.
$$
I will leave some other examples. For $x\leq 500$, I've found the following values
$$
\text{If }n=3,\,\,\,x\in\{22, 30, 67, 68, 79, 116, 128, 146, 165, 177, 191, 214, 226, 263, 275, \\
292, 312, 313, 315, 360, 373, 410, 422, 423, 429, 439, 459, 471, 484, \
499\}
$$

$$
\text{If }n=4,\,\,\,x\in\{1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 13, 17, 18, 21, 24, 25, 29, 32, 33, 35, 37, 38, 41, \\
43, 44, 45, 48, 49, 53, 57, 61, 62, 65, 69, 70, 71, 73, 74, 77, 81, \\
82, 85, 89, 93, 97, 98, 99, 101, 105, 107, 109, 113, 116, 117, 118, \\
120, 121, 125, 129, 132, 133, 137, 141, 143, 145, 146, 149, 152, 153, \\
157, 161, 165, 168, 169, 170, 173, 174, 177, 179, 181, 185, 189, 193, \\
195, 197, 199, 201, 205, 206, 207, 209, 213, 217, 218, 221, 224, 225, \\
229, 232, 233, 237, 241, 243, 244, 245, 249, 251, 253, 257, 260, 261, \\
265, 268, 269, 273, 274, 277, 278, 281, 282, 285, 287, 288, 289, 293, \\
297, 299, 301, 305, 309, 313, 314, 317, 321, 324, 325, 327, 329, 332, \\
333, 337, 341, 343, 345, 349, 353, 357, 359, 360, 361, 362, 365, 368, \\
369, 373, 377, 378, 381, 382, 385, 386, 389, 391, 393, 395, 397, 399, \\
401, 405, 407, 408, 409, 413, 417, 418, 421, 422, 424, 425, 429, 433, \\
437, 440, 441, 445, 449, 453, 457, 461, 465, 467, 468, 469, 473, 474, \\
476, 477, 481, 482, 483, 485, 489, 493, 494, 497, 500\}.
$$
It seems there are arbitrarily many values of $x$ for any $n$, maybe a good follow-up question is to understand whether that is true.

Comment: Edited question. Ty

Comment: Edited answer. I will see if I can find smaller values.

Comment: Found many cases, the smallest for $n=3$ is $x=22$.

Comment: Where did you come across such problem, if I may ask?

Comment: It is just from $x^2+ x+1$ cannot be a square.I guess now $x^3+x^2+x+1$ cannot be cube etc.That's another thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** When $n=2k$ then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x^{i-1}= (1+x) \left( 1+x^2+...+x^{2k-2}\right)$$

Then, whenever $1+x$ is divisible by a square, so is $\sum_{i=1}^n x^{i-1}$.

**Also** if $n=km$ then 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x^{i-1}=(1+x+x^2+...+x^{k-1})(1+x^{k}+x^{2k}+...+x^{mk-k})$$

Therefore, if $\sum_{i=1}^k x^{i-1}$ is divisble by a square, so is $\sum_{i=1}^n x^{i-1}$ for each multiple $n$ of $k$.